# Java: LinkedList

Tags: java, priority-queue

is there a way to say that if you reach the null reference, then do something ?
e.g. if i have a linkedlist with just one object and after this comparison, if you reached null then do something...

```
for(int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++) {
    if (queue.get(i).compareTo(newitem) == -1) {
                continue;
            }
}
```

for instance another if-clause in the loop saying

```
if (queue.equals(null)) {
    queue.add(newitem);
}
```

this is btw the linkedlist

```
public OrderedQueue() {
    queue = new LinkedList<T>(); // generate an empty queue
}
```

Comment: It might benefit you to provide a bit more detail in what you're wanting to do. The LinkedList class in Java has a getLast() method that you can use to add a new item if that's your intention.

Comment: I am sorry for my unclear question ! The problem is solved now :)

I just have one question as i am new here in stackoverflow ... how do i mark this post as done ? 

thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can always check that the object in your list is `null` to do a special operation:

```
for(Element e : queue) {
    if(e == null) {
        // special operation
    } else {
        // normal operation
    }
}
```

Also use a for-each loop to iterate over elements.

In your case, using the `get(i)` method is not very efficient on a `LinkedList`. Using a for each allows you to abstract the actual type of the `Iterable` you are iterating over.

Comment: I was just about to give exactly the same answer: 1) `for (T item : list) {...}` syntax, 2)`if (item == null) {...}` predicate.  You beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace everything with:

```
if (!queue.contains(newItem)) {
   queue.add(newItem);
}
```

Comment: Even better. Replace everything with `queue = new LinkedHashSet();` ... and then `queue.add(newItem)` ;)